How can we change the confirm button (cancel, ok) order of quasar framework's dialog plugin?
I can't figure out how to change the confirmation button order of quasar's dialog plugin. I want the ok button on the left and the canel button on the right but I couldn't find any information documentation. The only way seems to be Invoking custom component.
Dialog.create({
    title: "Confirm",
    message: "Are you sure?",
    ok: {
      label: "Yes",
      color: "positive",
    },
    cancel: {
      label: "No",
      color: "negative",
    }
  });

Are there any props for ok and cancel so we would modify the order?

As you noted, I don't think there is way outside of creating a custom dialog. I think your best shot in this case is to hack the CSS:
.q-card__actions {
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    /* align-items: normal; */
    justify-content: end !important;
}

https://codepen.io/bonatoc/pen/zYVWrpR
...but it's really not an elegant solution, not to mention possible CSS clashes.
Is there a particular reason for using the Dialog plugin instead of the Dialog Component, which gives you total freedom over the design of the dialog's content (including adding a specific CSS class to the dialog itself, so you can precisely target elements with CSS if needed?)

Yes, you're right—that approach seems to work. I initially found the $q.dialog method more convenient for small alerts and confirmations, mainly because it allows me to avoid repeating the underlying logic across multiple components. Using the Dialog Component would require incorporating the actual component with additional logic and values, which might be overkill for simpler cases. However, for more complex dialogs, the Dialog Component would indeed be the better choice. After your suggestion, I will review my decision to use $q.dialog instead. Thanks for your time!
